# how to generate form from json in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I make a form using jquery dform plugin .dform plugin convert the json object to HTML marmlup form .So now I am using angular can we have any API which convert the same thing mean json to HTML form .I goggled it but not found any thing .but jquery provide this plugin.can I use straight way this plugin ?
http://jsfiddle.net/Zt4Rz/2094/

```
$("#myform").dform({
    "action" : "index.html",
    "method" : "get",
    "html" :
    [
        {
            "type" : "p",
            "html" : "You must login"
        },
        {
            "name" : "username",
            "id" : "txt-username",
            "caption" : "Username",
            "type" : "text",
            "placeholder" : "E.g. user@example.com"
        },
        {
            "name" : "password",
            "caption" : "Password",
            "type" : "password"
        },
        {
            "type" : "submit",
            "value" : "Login"
        }
    ]
});
```

Is there any API in angular which convert the json to form ?

Thanks

Comment: It's not the Angular way: Angular does a separation between presentation and logic, so generating the view through logic -instead of doing simple data repetition- is not traditional into angular. There's no a "well known" package to do that, althought that doesn't say whether a 3rd party pkg exists or not.

Comment: how I will use this plugin

Comment: Have you ever read what I said?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no angular API or 3rd party package for that (correct me if I were wrong).

But you can easily use the existing jQuery plugin in your app - in AngularJS way - wrapping it into a `directive`:

```
yourModule.directive('dform', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      action: '@'
      method: '@'
      html: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      elm.dform({
          "action" : scope.action,
          "method" : scope.method,
          "html" : scope.html
      });
    }
  };
})
```

And then you can use the directive like this:

```
<div dform action="index.html" method="get" html="fields"></div>
```

And you put data (the `html` in your code) to `fields` in the back controller. This is how you separate logic and view.

All these code are just to show the way of doing it. You may need some tuning to get them to work with your app. And jQuery is still needed for the plugin to work.

**EDIT**

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4Ts4/1/) that demonstrates the solution.

Comment: can you please five plunker ..thanks for answer

Comment: just give a simple example so that I will unserstand properly

Comment: @user3665790 so the above code isn't qualified as a "simple example"? I would be happy to answer if you have specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer .I jsut want please make simple json as I take using directive make a form

Comment: I understand you give a good answer ,But it is imposible to understand without plunker .Please make a simple plunker..

Comment: @user3665790 Which part is the `json` you refer? The `html`?

Comment: as I used in fiddle .. "name" : "username",
            "id" : "txt-username",
            "caption" : "Username",
            "type" : "text",

Comment: please check my fiddle .if it possible make same example but in angular

Comment: @user3665790 Yes. Please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4Ts4/). Essentially it's same code as I put above...